# PendingIntent to launch and stop a Service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to make a simple widget with a button that start a `Service` with the `OnClickPendingIntent()`. I can start it fine but I can't figure out a way to stop it (I know I can do it with a `BroadcastReceiver` or something similar but I would like to avoid hardcode).

This is my code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

        if (!ismyserviceup(context)) {
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_button, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            // i need to stop it!!!!
        }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, here's one:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

    if (ismyserviceup(context)) {
        intent.setAction("STOP");
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);                
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_button, pendingIntent);
```

Then on the service's `onStartCommand()`, you can check the intent action for "STOP" (you should probably use a better string) and call `stopSelf()`.

Answer (score -1):

I created Xamarin android signal program, but when the signal comes, I can't show the signal, that is, the program does not open automatically

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33646956)