# Android - Notification pendingIntent to Stop Service

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have two notification actions, one to stop the service and one to restart it. 
I am successfully starting the service but I can't stop it with this code:

```
PendingIntent show = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, svc, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent hide = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, svc, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Any ideas?

Not a duplicate as my question is specifically about notification actions, not buttons (I have no problems getting my buttons to stop and start the service).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PendingIntent to launch and stop a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572216/pendingintent-to-launch-and-stop-a-service)

Comment: Why are you using the same request code for two different actions? I think you are confused with the PendingIntent Flags. The flags are used to control the notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That flag alone will not stop the service.  I would recommend that you make the stop action instead fire a custom `BroadcastReceiver` class which runs the `stopService()` method inside of its `onReceive()`.  Let me know if you need help setting something like that up in more detail.

Edited answer:

Change your `Intent` and `PendingIntent` for the hide action to this:

```
Intent intentHide = new Intent(this, StopServiceReceiver.class);

PendingIntent hide = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intentHide, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then make the `StopServiceReceiver` like this, where `ServiceYouWantStopped.class` is the service to be stopped:

```
public class StopServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 333;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, ServiceYouWantStopped.class);
        context.stopService(service);
    }
}
```

Make sure the `BroadcastReceiver` you just made is declared in your manifest file:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".StopServiceReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":remote" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No longer works with Android 26, it will simply print `BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed`